# How to use @admin-bro/nestjs with @admin-bro/typeorm and postgres in a right way?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, admin-bro

The admin-bro-nestjs repository contains a comprehensive example with example with mongoose. But I need use it with typeorm and postgres.
I tried to adapt this example for typeorm:

```
// main.ts
import AdminBro from 'admin-bro';
import { Database, Resource } from '@admin-bro/typeorm';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

AdminBro.registerAdapter({ Database, Resource });

const bootstrap = async () => {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

and

```
// app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AdminModule } from '@admin-bro/nestjs';
import { TypeOrmModule, getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { UserEntity } from './user/user.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 5432,
        username: 'postgres',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'database_test',
        entities: [UserEntity],
        synchronize: true,
        logging: false,
      }),
    AdminModule.createAdminAsync({
      imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity]),
      ],
      inject: [
        getRepositoryToken(UserEntity),
      ],
      useFactory: (userRepository: Repository<UserEntity>) => ({
        adminBroOptions: {
          rootPath: '/admin',
          resources: [
            { resource: userRepository },
          ],
        },
        auth: {
          authenticate: async (email, password) => Promise.resolve({ email: 'test' }),
          cookieName: 'test',
          cookiePassword: 'testPass',
        },
      }),
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But on application start I get the following error:

```
NoResourceAdapterError: There are no adapters supporting one of the resource you provided
```

Does anyone have any experience putting all these libraries together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also got `NoResourceAdapterError: There are no adapters supporting one of the resource you provided` when I tried to integrate AdminBro with NestJS/Express/TypeORM (though I'm using MySQL instead Postgres). The solution posted in the [admin-bro-nestjs Github issue which links to this question](https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/admin-bro-nestjs/issues/11) didn't help me.

The cause of `NoResourceAdapterError` for me simply was that `UserEntity` didn't extend `BaseEntity`. NestJS/TypeORM seems to work fine without extending `BaseEntity` but apparently it is required for AdminBro. You can see it used in the examples of the [AdminBro TypeORM adapter documentation](https://adminbro.com/module-@admin-bro_typeorm.html).

Here is an example which works for me.

```
// user.entity
import { Entity, BaseEntity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class UserEntity extends BaseEntity{
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  name: string;
}
```

```
// app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AdminModule } from '@admin-bro/nestjs';
 
import { Database, Resource } from '@admin-bro/typeorm';
import AdminBro from 'admin-bro'
AdminBro.registerAdapter({ Database, Resource });

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      // ...
    }),
    AdminModule.createAdmin({
        adminBroOptions: {
          resources: [UserEntity],
          rootPath: '/admin',
        },
    })
  ],
  // ...
})
```

Comment: this answer worked for me, saved me hours of debugging and checking what's wrong

Comment: I didn't think this would do anything, but turns out it was the root cause for me also.

Comment: My entities extends to BaseEntity, still the problem continues